# Attitude for solving $\int_{|z+1|=1} \frac{1}{z^{3}-i} d z$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I am asked to calculate $$\int_{|z+1|=1} \frac{1}{z^{3}-i} d z$$   I was thinking to apply the Cauchy integral theorem but I am not sure how to express the set $|z+1|=1$ as a boundary of  a disk in $\mathbb{C}$ can I write it as $D_1(-1)$?  something make me feel uncomfortable with the minus sign.

Comment: $|z+1|=1$ iff $|z-(-1)| = 1$ iff $(x-(-1))^2 + y^2 = 1$ iff $(x+1)^2 + y^2 = 1$, where $x$ and $y$ are the real and imaginary parts of $z$, respectively. So -- **yes**.

Comment: If your notation is that $D_r(p)$ is the disc of radius $r$ centred at the point $p$, then $D_1(-1)$ is correct. The centre happens to be a negative real number, but there's nothing wrong with that. (If the radius were negative, then that would be weird.)

Comment: And yes, the Cauchy Integral Formula is a great result to use here. (I know the [Cauchy Integral *Theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) as the special case when the function is *holomorphic* on the surrounded region, which is not the case here; but if you mean the more general [Cauchy Integral *Formula*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) when the function is *meromorphic* on the surrounded region, then that applies here and will be helpful.)

Comment: @TobyBartels Yes I meant for the  second formula you mentioned. I found it hard to handle with the denominator. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure what trouble you're having with the denominator, and you might want to write a different question. You can do a lot of the calculation just by noting that $\mathrm i$ has three distinct cube roots, one of which is in the disc, and callling them $a$, $b$, and $c$ (with $a$ the one in the disc). Then you can write $1/(z^3-\mathrm i)$ as $f(z)/(z-a)$, where $f(z)=1/(z-b)(z-c)$, and Cauchy's Integral Formula gives you $2\mathrm i\pi f(a)=2\mathrm i\pi/(a-b)(a-c)$ (assuming the integral is oriented counterclockwise). At this point, you work out what $a$, $b$, and $c$ are to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$|z+1| = 1$$
is the circle of radius $1$ centered at $-1+0\mathrm{i}$.  One can write this circle as $-1 + 1\cdot \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}$ allowing $0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi$ (or some translate of that interval).

More generally,
$$|z-a| = b$$
is the circle of radius $b$ centered at $a$.  One can write this circle as $a + b\cdot \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}$ allowing $0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi$ (or some translate of that interval).

Comment: Thank you, do you have any suggestion  how do I solve this integral?

Comment: @Sagigever : Partial fraction decomposition, the first part of which is factoring the denomator.  The roots are $-\mathrm{i}$ and two of the sixth roots of $-1$.  (You'll have to figure out which two.)  You'll find only one of the roots is in the circle.  Find the residue of that root and use the Cauchy integral formula.